# call JavaScript in jsp page from servlet

Tags: javascript, java

I would like to call JavaScript function which is in jsp page from servlet. Test() is the function i need to call... The name of the JSP page is Test.jsp and the name of the servlet page is Sample.java . cti_toolbar_test is my project name .Here is my jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/*javascript*"> 
function Test()
    {
        alert("Success");
    }
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

here is my servlet code

```
out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");  
out.println("alert('the session did time out, please reconnect');"); 
out.println("<script src=\"/cti_toolbar_test/Test.jsp\">");
out.println("Test();");
out.println("</script>");
```

Kindly Suggest Me

Comment: which kind of error u got with ur code

Comment: Where is the servlet code in relation to the above html code?

Comment: On loading my servlet i am getting an empty page not an error

Comment: code at the second block is my servlet code